# How can I keep float numbers for step in ion-range

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I m using ionic 3 and to increment ionic range input component by 0.25
this is the [components documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/)

using step="0.5" like above did not work

`<ion-range class="note-range" min="0" max="20" step="0.5" [(ngModel)]="item.note" color="secondary" (ionChange)="noteChanged($event)">
    <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
    <ion-label range-right>20</ion-label>
 </ion-range>`

so i followed the solution above given by ["Jahdere"](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-keep-float-numbers-for-step-in-ion-range/67347)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Range } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'float-range',
  template: '<ion-range #range [min]="min" [max]="max" [pin]="pin" [step]="step" [snaps]="snaps"></ion-range>'

})
export class FloatRangeComponent {

  @Input() max: number;
  @Input() min: number;
  @Input() pin: boolean;
  @Input() step: number;
  @Input() snaps: boolean;

  @ViewChild('range')
  set range(range: Range) {
    let floatRange: FloatRangeComponent = this;
    range._ratioToValue = function(ratio: number) {
      this._step = Math.round(floatRange.step * 100) / 100;
      ratio = (this._max - this._min) * ratio;
      ratio = (ratio / this._step) * this._step + this._min;
      return Math.round(ratio * ( 1 / this._step)) / ( 1 / this._step);
    }
  }
}
```

the problem with this solution is when i use ngModel on the float-range component i m getting this error :

> Runtime Error when using ngModel on float-range component. : No value
>   accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

is there any solution to bind ngModel data between those two components ?

Answer (score 0):

Hej Guys,

just pipe your value for your ngModel via input from the float-range to the ion-range component!

```
<float-range [_ngModel]="item.value"></float-range>
```

In your float-range component bind your input to the ngModel of the ion-range:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'float-range',
  template: `<ion-range #range [min]="min" [max]="max" [pin]="pin" [step]="step" [snaps]="snaps" [(ngModel)]="_ngModel" (ionBlur)="onValueChange($event);" ngDefaultControl></ion-range>`
})
export class FloatRangeComponent {

  @Input() max: number;
  @Input() min: number;
  @Input() pin: boolean;
  @Input() step: number;
  @Input() snaps: boolean;
  @Input() _ngModel: any;
```